# The button that I have in the datatable does not work on the second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Below are my codes I'm using currently. Can someone help as this is important.

```
$("#btn" + arr[i].numberID).on("click", { id: arr[i].numberID }, function (event) {
  var data = event.data;
  getdet(data.id);
});

function getdet(numberID) {
  window.location = "order.html?numberID=" + numberID;
}
```

Comment: `function 
    getdet(data.id);
  });` makes no sense

Comment: i have edited it. Accidentally included it when typing in stackoverflow

Comment: Can you clarify what "does not work" mean? Also, what's "the second page"?

Comment: i am using the Pagination currently where it allow the datatable to have a second page. The button that i set for each row can work for the first page but not the remaining pages

Comment: And when you direct access `order.html?numberID=" + numberID` for second page it didn't work also?? or it just not working on button click

Comment: it just not working on button click

Comment: ok try to write the full url something like ` window.location.href = "http:://www.yourwebsite.com/order.html?numberID=" + numberID;` and see what you got

Comment: i am coding this for a mobile app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about this, but I think your issue is that the click event listener is not binding to the buttons in the other pages(the reason being that the buttons are dynamically generated when you change pages). 
This article explains the problem: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements).
Try if this works:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn" + arr[i].numberID, { id: arr[i].numberID }, function (event) {
  var data = event.data;
  getdet(data.id);
});

function getdet(numberID) {
  window.location = "order.html?numberID=" + numberID;
}
```

Hope this helps.